# URI to Class Object in ModernUI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uri

Hi i am using Modern UI and Its loading ".xaml" file by ContentSource and link parameter. So i am stuck with the .xaml Class Object. How could we get the Class Object reference by Content Source or say URI.

My Main class file code is as below

```
public partial class MainWindow : ModernWindow
{
     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         this.ContentSource = new Uri("Pages/Home.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
     }
}
```

i want Home.xaml object as Home Class Object. i tried to create a new Home Object as

```
Home homapge = new Home();
```

But its creating a new Home class Object not that one, which is used in Cotent Source.

So please help me to get this object.

Comment: Yes i am calling Home in MainWindow. Just tried this again. Getting error : "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." i am calling a public method just after that : homePage.init();

Comment: There is nothing inside init function of Home Class. Issue is with Home homepage = (Home)this.Content; because just after this line if i try to Console.WriteLine(homePage.ToString()); that also giving same error.

Comment: How can i use Loaded event?